# Why omitting of structure property reports compile-time error

Tags: swift, structure

I'm study the swift by the Apple's official book "The Swift Programming Language" and faced a compilation error. I create a structure which has two properties with default values. And attempt to initialise with only one parameter results in a compilation error. What a reason of it?

```
struct Size {
    var width = 0.0, height = 0.0
}

let twoByTwo = Size(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
let zeroByTwo = Size(height: 2.0)
let zeroByZero = Size()
```

Comment: Please add more details and error

Comment: That code requires Swift 5.1/Xcode 11 beta.

Comment: Look at this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56683932/919545 for more info

Comment: Mohindra's answer below is the correct one. A side note to your code tho is that structs should never be mutable, hence you will always want to use `let` when declaring the values. And by looking at the naming  i guess you want to use this for a `CGSize` in a later moment. Which then would be neat to create a computed property. `var size: CGSize {return CGSize(width: width, height: height)}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Swift whenever we are going to create a structure. Swift automatically creates the default initializer for the particular structure. In your case, you will get a compile-time error in `let zeroByTwo = Size(height: 2.0)`.

[image]

Because you are not passing all the parameters required by the default initializer. to fix that issue you can create your own `init()` functions in your structure as shown below.

```
struct Size {
    var width:Double, height:Double

    init(width:Double = 0.0, height:Double = 0.0){
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
    }
}

let twoByTwo = Size(width: 2.0, height: 2.0)
let zeroByTwo = Size(width: 2.0)
let zeroByZero = Size()
```

Comment: It's the correct answer, but you should edit it to make the init params have default values. To avoid multiple inits. As your approach is kinda Java'ish. And don't use images of code as answer.

Comment: Still errors or at least warnings in the init as you have them as optionals and yet default value 0.0