# Swift ui codable struct with empty fields

Tags: swift, codable, decodable

I have the following structs:

```swift
struct ResponseToken: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { return UUID() }
    let access_token: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case access_token
    }
}

struct ResponseUserInfo: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    var id: UUID { return UUID() }
    let login, avatar_url, html_url, created_at, updated_at: String
    let public_repos, public_gists, followers, following: Int
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case login, avatar_url, html_url, public_repos, public_gists, followers, following, created_at, updated_at
    }
}
```

I would like to avoid doing this every time to declare empty objs:

```swift
var token: ResponseToken = ResponseToken(access_token: "")

var userInfo: ResponseUserInfo =
ResponseUserInfo(login: "", avatar_url: "", html_url: "", created_at: "", updated_at: "", public_repos: 0, public_gists: 0, followers: 0, following: 0)
```

The result I would like to have is something like this:

```swift
var token: ResponseToken = ResponseToken()
var userInfo: ResponseUserInfo = ResponseUserInfo()
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't initialize a struct with a default value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923240/cant-initialize-a-struct-with-a-default-value)

Comment: You many find this helpful https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Initialization.html

Comment: `var id: UUID { return UUID() }` returns a new id every time. Not just the first time. Whenever you ask the struct for it's `id` you will always get a new value.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is a static property which creates an empty struct for example

```
struct ResponseToken: Identifiable, Codable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let accessToken: String
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case accessToken = "access_token"
    }

    static let empty = ResponseToken(accessToken: "")
}
```

and use it

```
let token = ResponseToken.empty
```

Notes:

- The computed property to return an UUID is pointless, declare a constant.
- If you are specifying `CodingKeys` anyway, use them also to convert the snake_case keys.